# Why my pushbutton always reads LOW?

Tags: arduino-uno

This is the code I used in  my project

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5,INPUT);
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println(digitalRead(5));
  if(digitalRead(5)==HIGH){
    blink(12,100);
    blink(11,100);
    blink(10,100);
    blink(9,100);
    blink(8,100);
    blink(7,100);
    blink(6,100);
    Serial.println("blink done");
  }
  
}
void blink(int a,int b)
{
  digitalWrite(a,HIGH);
  delay(b);
  digitalWrite(a,LOW);
  delay(b);
}
```

[image: Image of Tinkercad of my work]

> Project link
> https://www.tinkercad.com/things/55vY18FFxDR-blinking-led-wave/editel?sharecode=xQAM80Uu6sJ-hBnLLd04KasomJ2eNNzWLgKZMARe4ig

Comment: connect only the switch, resistor and LED ... determine which two pins are connected when you press the button ... I suspect that the top left pin is always connected to the bottom left pin

Comment: L1 and L2 or R1 and R2(L for left, R for Right) are connected when the button is open.

[link]https://www.tinkercad.com/things/kMT2yOJpFzg-analog-read/editel?returnTo=%2Fdashboard%3Fcollection%3Ddesigns%26type%3Dcircuits&sharecode=OoTMPbTeJWJGX6WAKZCwLJWxiERzOEBsVfjqZH9p4Kw

this is where I checked it.

Comment: you have brown wire connected to L1, which is always connected to L2, and L2 is connected to ground ... why are you surprised that the brown wire is always grounded?

Comment: Yes I am aware of it, but the issue I am concerned about is that it neither displays 1 nor does the blink function after pressing the button. I tried moving the D5 pin jumper to j30 and it displayed 1 and the blink started to work (as R1 and R2 are connected but it defies the purpose of switch).

Comment: You mean when you short 5V to GND by pressing button (that is how you have that wired), it's not working? Maybe polyfuse is taking some time to reset, or USB port protection

Comment: remove the 5 V wire at a30 ... move D5 to j30 ... enable internal pullup resistor `pinMode(5,INPUT_PULLUP);`

Comment: I changed the if condition digitalRead as LOW and as @jsotola said I have changed the pinMode to INPUT_PULLUP, *IT WORKED*...somehow....

It is highly appreciated if you could explain why the 5 v wire and that typical pushbutton connection didn't work

Comment: in the circuit above, D5 is always connected to GND ... connecting 5 V to GND does not do anything to raise the voltage at D5 ... in a real circuit, a connection between 5 V and GND could easily damage something

Comment: Understood but why the below given typical pushbutton circuit even works and not here.
Is it possible to remake that pushbutton here......?

My simulation references:
https://imgur.com/a/jUagd1q     (image)

https://imgur.com/a/vnZSJ6H     (video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press the button, you short the bottom blue (GND) and the bottom red (+5V) lines. That will in the least serious case cause your Arduino to reset, but could also damage the button, burn a wire or a capacitor, or brick your Arduino. There's some protection on the board to prevent serious damage or even injury to someone, but still you should **absolutely avoid** shorting +5V to GND.

The fix is actually quite simple: Replace the short blue wire with a large resistor, something like 10k. Then the Button will still read low when it's not pressed, but read high when it's pressed. That's called a "pull-down" resistor.

Comment: the OP is running a simulation ... the short circuit probably is not simulated ... your answer is applicable to real hardware only

Comment: That's an point to be noted but it did not work here as it is just a simulation.